# How to find the path of where a Ruby Gem is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I have just installed cucumber and bundler in my MAC and I get this error message:

```
Error creating formatter: Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter (ArgumentError)

gem 'cucumber', version
load Gem.bin_path('cucumber', 'cucumber', version)
```

Comment: What's your cucumber version?

Comment: My  cucumber version is 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17157), `cucumber >= 2.1.0` is not supported yet.  You can downgrade, wait for an update, or use their suggested monkey patch:

> find in RubyMine folder file named "formatter_03103.rb" and replace
>   line 22 to
>
> ```
>  def initialize(step_mother, path_or_io, options)
> ```
>
> and line 24 to
>
> ```
> tc_initialize(options, '|', path_or_io)
> ```

And the command `gem environment` returns lots of info about your gems, including the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`.